# How to clear non Widget contents in the HTML page in smartgwt

Tags: html, smartgwt

In my smartgwt application, the html page contains some code consisting of a div and a table.

This is show to the user until the call to server is completed. Once this is done, I want to remove the div and the table from the html page, how can I do that?

**PS**: I tried **RootPanel.get("body").clear()** and **RootPanel.get("divID").removeFromParent()**
and both didn't work

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
yourDivOrElementToRemove= DOM.getElementById("idOfTheElement");
```

`DOM.removeChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), yourDivOrElementToRemove);`

Regards

Alain